# How to properly incorporate Zurb Foundation & Compass to configure SASS variables for a Wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, sass, zurb-foundation, compass-sass

I have been using foundation to develop a Wordpress theme by creating a custom build on the website and including the required files in my theme.

The theme structure (simplified) is so:

```
Theme Root
|-- 404.php
|-- _
|   |-- inc
|   |   |-- css
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   `-- foundation.min.css
|   |   |-- images
|   `-- js
|       |-- foundation.min.js
|       `-- modernizr.js
|-- theme.css
|-- theme.scss
```

My issue is that I would like to customise the SCSS variables, e.g.:

```
/* Background color for the top bar */
$topbar-bg: #111;
```

And have tried to include the necessary components:

```
@import "foundation/components/topbar";
$include-html-top-bar-classes: $include-html-classes;
```

Clearly it isn't finding the classes as there is no compass project or appropriate SCSS files to import/include, so this is where my question comes in.

I've installed the foundation gem, and am able to create a new Compass project, but I'm just wondering how to structure things and setup/update my Wordpress theme as a Compass project so I can set the variables in `_settings.scss`?

I'm just a bit confused as to how the 'foundation' way would be to go about incorporating it into a Wordpress theme so that I can customise the necessary SCSS variables while maintaining a standard Wordpress theme structure?

Comment: Ok, by rephrasing my thinking apart from foundation and focusing on Compass + Wordpress, I came across [this tip](http://css-tricks.com/compass-compiling-and-wordpress-themes/) from Chris Coyier. I managed to get a setup I'm happy with, it primarily boils down to setting up the `config.rb` the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what level of integration you're looking for you need to create the foundation project in your theme's template directory. I use Foundation 4, SCSS & SMACSS mostly and here's a quick CL snippet I have for this:

```
compass create templatename -r zurb-foundation --using foundation; cd templatename/sass; mkdir {functions,layouts,mixins,modules,vendor}; open ../;
```

Now, that said if the theme is already in existence you will want to create templatename with . as it means use the folder you're in already. I don't have a good CL way to do Foundation 5 yet because most of my projects rely on IE compatibility still. Hopefully this gets you going in the right direction, but with the compass create you'll be able to use watch & compile and import different things.

Also, if you're interested in SMACSS (which is awesome) check out http://smacss.com